# Set transient name

Tags: transient

I am using wordpress REST api to provide certain data from website to app server.
This custom route is used to send default image and everything works fine.
Now I want to use set_transient, I used following code to do so.

```
    $transient='apidata_json_cache';
    $expiration =2*60; // 2 Minutes

    if(false === ($feed=get_transient($transient))) {
        echo '<!--Fresh data-->';

        /*data extraction process here, which is than stored in $feed*/

        set_transient($transient,$feed,$expiration);  
    }
```

Now each time run the code. The transient is stored with name "_transient__default_thumbnail", _default_thumbnail is the name of one of the ACF field used during extraction of data.

```
$images['_default_thumbnail'] = get_field('_default_thumbnail','options');
```

I dont want to save transient with that name. Can you please help  to find out what is wrong or what am I missing while creating transient.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks you're using different transient names in get_ and set_.

Try the following:

```
$transient_key = 'apidata_json_cache';
$expiration = 2*60; // 2 Minutes

if( false === ( $feed = get_transient( $transient_key ) ) ) {
    echo '<!--Fresh data-->';

    /*data extraction process here, which is than stored in $feed*/

    set_transient( $transient_key, $feed, $expiration );  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, my original code has same transient name for both set and get transient. I have edited the question. I don't know what is wrong with this code. Looks like  ACF and set_transient are having some sort of cross connection.